# mySQL: Load a CHAR VALUE taken as substring from another VALUE

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL newbie question:

I have a child table 'Outputs', that takes two values:

```
CREATE TABLE Outputs ( 
sub_id char(13) NOT NULL, 
output varchar(255), 
output_id smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
PRIMARY KEY (output_id)
);
```

output is a path string, such as :

```
/full/path/to/output/client_xxx/client_xxx_final_output.txt
```

I want to load data from a file, or insert by hand for practice.

The sub_id is 'client_XXX' which is part of the path, and will always
be the case. So I'd like to take the sub_id from the path.

I've seen the SET clause and user parameters @var used in examples, but I'm getting lost
trying to get the sub string ( correct function to use ? ) and in getting all the 
SQL commands in the proper order is difficult for beginner.

Cheers !

EDIT:

I wasn't very clear what my ultimate goal is.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Outputs (sub_id, output) VALUES
% SET @path_string = foobar, then substring command
```

Sorry for being vague I'm still wrapping my head around SQL syntax.

Comment: Have you looked at the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function? It's useful for exactly this type of thing.

Comment: I did look at the function but I don't think I was calling it correctly. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Show us what you tried, then we can tell you how you went wrong. You don't learn anything by just copying code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is always the second-to-last element:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(output, '/', -2), '/', 1)
```

If it just starts with "client" somewhere, you can use string manipulations as well.  The above is simpler, so I'll start there.

EDIT:

If the data is already in a table, then you want `update`:

```
update outputs o
    set sub_id = substring_index(substring_index(output, '/', -2), '/', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer...I didn't organize my question as well as it could be. I'm also a little lost as how to combine your command, with the INSERT statement. I think this requires SET clause ?

Comment: I feel like I need to just read more and try some easier examples of manipulating values on the fly. 'm accepting this answer since it helped me get started and showed use of substring_index. Thank you all for your effort.